# wcf reference not being generated correctly

Tags: vb.net, wcf

Ran across a weird problem with my WCF references this morning. In a nutshell, I have a duplex service set up so that a server can notify a client by sending objects in a data contract. When a client connects, it runs a function on the server to return a `List(Of NewItem)` based on what's in the shared queue of the service class. The trouble is, when I update my service reference in the client, it says the function returns a `NewItem` object, not a `List(Of NewItem)` object. I can go into the reference and manually change it to a `List` object and it'll transfer just fine. Any ideas why the service reference generator would arbitrarily change my return type?

Here's the relevant code:

```
<ServiceContract(
    CallbackContract:=GetType(INotifyCallback),
    SessionMode:=ServiceModel.SessionMode.Required)>
Public Interface INotifyService
    <OperationContract()>
    Function GetNewServerItems() As List(Of NewItem)
End Interface

<DataContract>
<Serializable>
Public Class NewItem
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property ItemNum As String

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Timestamp As DateTime
End Class

<ServiceBehavior(
    ConcurrencyMode:=ServiceModel.ConcurrencyMode.Single,
    InstanceContextMode:=ServiceModel.InstanceContextMode.Single)>
Public Class NotifyService
    Implements INotifyService

    Shared _server_items As New List(Of NewItem)

    Public Function GetNewServerItems() As List(Of NewItem)
        Return _server_items
    End Function
End Class
```

And in Reference.vb (simplified):

```
<System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://tempuri.org/INotifyService/GetNewServerItems", ReplyAction:="http://tempuri.org/INotifyService/GetNewServerItemsResponse")>  _
Function GetNewServerItems() As NotifyGateway.NewItem()
```

Comment: Did you add your referency by right clicking your project and selecting "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: Did you leave off `<ServiceContract>` by accident?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - not by accident. I left them out because it's a long contract and I wanted to include only the bare bones. I've added them in.

Comment: A slight, but important clarification to your original post: the function returns an array of NewItem objects, not a single NewItem object. You could easily create a List(Of NewItem) on the receiving side and load it from the array or just use the array as-is if changing the default Collection Type causes other side effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You and I fell into the same trap: we both misread the VB.NET code generated for the proxy method as returning a single item. In fact, it is returning an array.

WSDL uses XML Schema to describe the shape of the request and response. XML Schema has no concept of a "list", only of a sequence. By default, when it sees a sequence of items, "Add Service Reference" generates an array. You can change this to generate a "List", simply by changing the collection type on the "Advanced" tab of the "Add Service Reference" or "Configure Service Reference" dialogs.

Comment: ...you're right. `NewItem` is not the same as `NewItem()`. Should have noticed that.

Answer (score 1):

When adding a reference the way you did, you should change the "Collection type" in the Advanced Service Reference Settings (Add Service Reference dialog) to "system.Collections.Generic.List". By default it is "System.Array".

I would not recomend though using the Add Reference way because you lose control over the configuration of your WCF service, and VS adds a lot of garbage that you do not need, and that would make your client/service link harder to maintain.

Hope this helps.

Comment: -1: Please don't make such recommendations without more substantiation. Also, not without asking which .NET version he's using, as .NET 4.0 produces a much smaller config file by omitting defaults.

Comment: The first part of the answer seems to fix the immediate problem. Regarding the second part of the answer: how else would I add a service reference or otherwise get my contract to work without using the "Add Service Reference" method? (And yes, I am using .NET 4.)

Comment: Right, sorry about that. I did not mean the configuration file, I meant that when using "Add Service Reference" the result is incredibly verbose, hard to manage and maintain, configuration changes could get overwrite, instead of reusing your interface it generates a duplicate. So IMHO, manually configuring WCF (manually or with the appropiate tool) is the best way to go, and I should have put it like that before. Hope this makes my answer clearer, and sorry once more.

Answer (score 1):

There is another, less well-known, but more powerful mechanism for preserving the collection types without resorting to using the default collection type setting.

This mechanism is especially useful if you have CollectionDataContract classes that you use in your code on both sides of a WCF pipe.

The solution involves editing the svcmap that is generated as part of the WCF service reference and adding specific CollectionMapping entries for each of the collection types that you want to serialize. The primary thing to watch out for here is generics: if WCF finds more than one match for a given class, it will refuse to generate the code.

To actually make the changes:

1) Show all of the files in the project which contains your WCF service reference.

2) Expand your service reference

3) Double-click on the Reference.svmap file to edit it.

4) Add your entries in the CollectionMappings section (if it does not exist, you can add it).

For example, in order to transfer generic Dictionaries and Lists, and to transfer StringCollections, you can have the following entries:

```
<CollectionMappings>
  <CollectionMapping TypeName="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2" Category="Dictionary" />
  <CollectionMapping TypeName="System.Collections.Generic.List`1" Category="List" />
  <CollectionMapping TypeName="System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection" Category="List" />
<CollectionMappings>
```

The first item with a category of Dictionary will serve as the default Dictionary collection type and the first item with a category of List will serve as the default Collection type.

We have over 200 collection classes that we use this way for Silverlight and Windows Forms clients and it is an extremely efficient way to reuse your own code on both sides of a WCF pipe.

One important note: to reuse your classes, you need to ensure that the "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" flag in the service reference configuration is checked or that that the GenerateInternalTypes flag in the reference.svmap is set to false (these are the same thing).